# hide rows in excel workbook using office.js

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

We are building an excel addin using office.js. We want to hide a range of rows. I checked the [Excel Javascript API Documentation](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins?product=excelhttps://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins?product=excel). I did not find any solution for that.

Could someone please help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Office.js, you can programmatically hide and unhide rows by updating the **rowHidden** property on the range object. The following example shows how to hide rows 2-5 in **Sheet1**.

```
Excel.run(function (context) {

    // Hide rows 2-5 in 'Sheet1'
    var range = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("2:5");
    range.rowHidden = true;

    return context.sync()
        .then(function() {
            console.log("Rows 2-5 have been hidden.");
        });
}).catch(function (error) {
        OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
});
```

To unhide rows in a range, set the **rowHidden** property to **false**.  You can find documentation of the **rowHidden** property (and the **columnHidden** property, for hiding/unhiding columns) here in the Excel API Reference docs: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/range.

Comment: I am very new to this excel addin development. I have seen that property but used that before the line "console.log('Rows 2-5 have been hidden.');" That why it was not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Kim Brandi's answer is good. If you are working with tables another option that might be useful depending on your scenario is to hide rows by filtering. See the [Table](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/table) and [TableColumn](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/tablecolumn) reference topics.